# Error: Unbound variable in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have the following code in Scheme

```
(define (serie A B)
    (if (> A B)
        (
            (define AB (* A B))
            (write AB)
        )
        (
            (write "No")
        )  
    )
)
```

When I call this function, the following error appears:
prog.scm:5:53:Unbound variable

Why is this happening?

Comment: The specific error reported is caused by that misplaced `define`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, the parentheses are *not* used for delimiting blocks of code, unlike curly braces in other programming languages. And you can't `define` a variable inside another expression (you can do it only at the beginning of the procedure); use a `let` instead. The correct way to structure and indent your code is:

```
(define (serie A B)
  (if (> A B)
      (let ((AB (* A B)))
        (write AB))
      (write "No")))
```

Of course, you don't really need a local variable, and you should write the result of the multiplication directly:

```
(define (serie A B)
  (if (> A B)
      (write (* A B))
      (write "No")))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(serie 10 20)
=> "No"
(serie 100 20)
=> 2000
```

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot, I have to understand `define` expression because it is confusing to me. Where can I find good information about this programming language and functional programming in general?

Comment: @Lemark I recommend  "How to design programs" or "The Little Schemer"

Comment: @Lemark "How to design programs" is available [here](http://www.htdp.org).